# Load Balancing Measure ping Using PHP/unix command

Tags: php, unix, networking

I'm building an application which uses load balancing to transfer users to another server. However i want to use a more smart solution than simple redirecting.

It is possible to ping the client's IP somehow using PHP or a simple Unix Command. I want to transfer the user to the server with the lower ping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this: [Pinging an IP address using PHP and echoing the result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8030789/pinging-an-ip-address-using-php-and-echoing-the-result)

Specifically:

```
pingresult = exec("/bin/ping -n 3 $ip", $outcome, $status);
```

Or this: [PHP - get server to ping a visitors IP and return the ping in ms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7555846/php-get-server-to-ping-a-visitors-ip-and-return-the-ping-in-ms)

```
<?php

$out = array();
exec('ping -c 4 '.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $out);
print_r($out);

?>
```

**EDIT**

You could try using microtime to measure the execution on the server (which should account for network travel time as well)

[Accurate way to measure execution times of php scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6245971/accurate-way-to-measure-execution-times-of-php-scripts)

Comment: Yes but in most cases a server is unable to ping the given IP so pinging like this isnt not an option. Could a script that sending data to client and measure the total time taken to transfer the data would work?

Comment: I have added an edit.  As per your original question, you specifically mentioned the use of a UNIX command.  It should be noted that your clients are unreachable by a standard ping.